# How to use XML comments with #if !SYMBOL

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xml-comments, preprocessor-directive

I'm trying to use C# XML comments in conjunction with conditional directive.

With `#if SYMBOL` it works:

```
    /// <summary>Some summary.</summary>
    #if SYMBOL
    /// <remarks>Conditional remark</remarks>
    #endif
    public bool IsSupported { get; set; }
```

With negative preprocessor directive `#if !SYMBOL` it does not work:

```
    /// <summary>Some summary.</summary>
    #if !SYMBOL
    /// <remarks>Conditional remark</remarks>
    #endif
    public bool IsSupported { get; set; }
```

It produces following warning: `XML comment is not placed on a valid language element`. Moreover it includes the `remarks` element, but removes the `summary` element from the resulting XML documentation.

**Update**

With `#if` and `#else` blocks results are similar to `#if !SYMBOL`. Same warning produced by a `summary` element and no `summary` in the output.

```
    /// <summary>Some summary.</summary>
    #if SYMBOL
    /// <remarks>SYMBOL defined</remarks>
    #else
    /// <remarks>SYMBOL not defined</remarks>
    #endif
    public bool IsSupported { get; set; }
```

Any workaround for this? I'm using VS 2010 and C# 4.0.

Comment: Does putting the comment in an `#else` clause work?

Comment: With `#else` the result is similar to `#if !SYMBOL`. I've updated question with details.

Comment: I suspect that #if results in a newline...

Comment: I just tried this (VS2010 SP1, c# 4.0) using `DEBUG` as the symbol and I did not get any warnings.

Comment: Look at [How to use #if in an XML comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70007076/how-to-use-if-in-an-xml-comment/70016630#70016630) for a possible solution.